# Issue with Status bar in UITableViewController (SidebarController)

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode6, statusbar, uistatusbar

I am using UITableViewController in sidebar and I am having status bar as white in my application. I am using a SidebarDemo Library with SWRevealViewController in my application. Everything is working fine, only my issue is when I open my Sidebar , it show white space on top, that is little weired in the application and mentioned in screenshot below.[image: Status bar issue]

I tried hiding my status bar by code below

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

//    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
//    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
//    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

    //self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
```

But tableView is not moving up. My Sidebar Class having heading of Profile in TableView is inherited from UITableViewController.  Please advice how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this Sidebar Demo app as well. I had some issues with this `SideBarViewController`. I fixed those issues. In your case first of all try to change the tintColor of the status bar in the `MainViewController`.

```
_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:94.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:19.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

By Default it would be like this

```
_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.9f];
```

AND

You can also change the `SideBarViewController` from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` and implement the `UITableViewDelegates` in the `SideBarViewController` and do all the customization to the View in Storyboard. This is what I did to the fix the issues I had.

Lemme know if I could help you with this SideBar Demo app code.